# AdMob won't load banners on Jelly Bean, ReferenceError, AMFA_getSdkConstants not defined 

Tags: android, admob, referenceerror

I am using the admob sdk (6.1.0) to show two banners on top of my custom ListFragments with this code in each fragment at onActivityCreated():

```
LinearLayout adLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
adView = new AdView(getActivity(), AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
adLayout.addView(adView);
getListView().addHeaderView(adLayout);
```

everything works fine on my old LG Optimus 2X on Ginger Bread but now i have a Samsung Galaxy S3 on Jelly Bean and my ads won't show up anymore!
I'm getting this error:

```
09-24 23:07:35.661: I/Ads(24043): Refreshing ad.
09-24 23:07:35.691: I/webclipboard(24043): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42a88b90
09-24 23:07:35.696: V/webkit(24043): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42cc0c00}
09-24 23:07:35.726: I/Ads(24043): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":2,"session_id":"16934128083720156505","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"3","slotname":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","u_w":360,"msid":"com.thiost.android.twire","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.1.0","toar":2,"mv":"8014017.com.android.vending","isu":"605557A27D3A2A6A54663D68CFF48311","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"903.android.com.thiost.android.twire","hl":"nl","u_h":640,"carrier":"20404","ptime":120187,"u_audio":3});</script></head><body></body></html>
09-24 23:07:35.916: E/Ads(24043): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (about:blank:1)
09-24 23:07:35.916: E/Web Console(24043): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined:1
09-24 23:08:35.716: I/Ads(24043): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
09-24 23:08:35.721: D/webviewglue(24043): nativeDestroy view: 0x531a3420
09-24 23:08:35.726: I/Ads(24043): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
09-24 23:09:35.786: I/Ads(24043): Refreshing ad.
09-24 23:09:35.811: I/webclipboard(24043): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42a88b90
09-24 23:09:35.821: V/webkit(24043): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42d893c0}
09-24 23:09:35.851: I/Ads(24043): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":3,"session_id":"16934128083720156505","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"4","slotname":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","u_w":360,"msid":"com.thiost.android.twire","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.1.0","toar":3,"mv":"8014017.com.android.vending","isu":"605557A27D3A2A6A54663D68CFF48311","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"903.android.com.thiost.android.twire","hl":"nl","u_h":640,"carrier":"20404","ptime":240317,"u_audio":3});</script></head><body></body></html>
09-24 23:09:35.881: D/dalvikvm(24043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1150K, 26% free 14863K/20039K, paused 6ms+5ms, total 50ms
09-24 23:09:35.996: E/Ads(24043): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (about:blank:1)
09-24 23:09:35.996: E/Web Console(24043): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined:1
```

I'm only getting this error when the app loads an add for the first time on a WiFi connection. All the other times on WiFi it gives me this error:

```
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165): IOException connecting to ad url.
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to googleads.g.doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at com.google.ads.internal.f.b(SourceFile:459)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at com.google.ads.internal.f.run(SourceFile:430)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-25 17:29:37.600: W/Ads(23165):   ... 16 more
```

It doesn't give errors on a mobile internet connection...

Comment: The key is `09-24 23:08:35.726: I/Ads(24043): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)` Are you sure you have a network connection?

Comment: Are you targeting Ice Cream Sandwich? You will fail trying to run network processes in the foreground. New rule. Network can only run in the background on ICS and above. If you can, target and min SDK for 2x. It will then run in compat mode and work. Or not.

Comment: I have already set the target and min SDK to 7 and 9 (tried both) and I am really sure I have a internet connection because other network related stuf in my app do work.

Comment: I found out today that the problem only exists when I am connected to WiFi. When I am on my mobile internet it does work! And it doesn't give any errors! Very strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.
I had flashed a new rom that installed a new hosts file wich was blocking my ads...
After deleting the hosts file the ads were displayed